# gcd of two numbers one of them is too large

Tags: math, numbers, modulo, greatest-common-divisor

I was going through a question which ask to calculate gcd(a-b,a^n+b^n)%(10^9+7) where a,b,n can be as large as 10^12.

I am able to solve this for a,b and n for very small numbers and fermat's theorem also didn't seem to work, and i reached a conclusion that if a,b are coprime then this will always give me gcd as 2 but for the rest i am not able to get it?

i need just a little hint that what i am doing wrong to get gcd for large numbers? I also tried x^y to find gcd by taking modulo at each step but that also didn't work.

Need just direction and i will make my way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into exponentiation by squaring? `n = 10^12` is smallish from the point of view of e.g. cryptography where modular exponentiation with exponents around 2^512 is routine.

Comment: yes i used it to but for (10^12)^(10^12) there is no place to store that number and if i take modulo at each step it would not be correct as gcd will be different or correct me if i am doing something wrong?

Comment: i am calculating a^n and b^n individually so if i find gcd(a-b, a^n+b^n)%10^9+7 as it will give me wrong answer and if i take modulo a^n%10^9+7 at each step still it will give me wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `a^n + b^n` is too large to compute and that working mod 10^9 + 7 at each step doesn't provide a way to compute the answer. But, you can still use modular exponentiation by squaring with a *different* modulus, namely `a-b`

Key observations:

```
1) gcd(a-b,a^n + b^n) = gcd(d,a^n + b^n) where d = abs(a-b)
2) gcd(d,a^n + b^n) = gcd(d,r) where r = (a^n + b^n) % d
3) r can be feasibly computed with modular exponentiation by squaring
```

The point of 1) is that different programming languages have different conventions for handling  negative numbers in the mod operator. Taking the absolute value avoids such complications, though mathematically it doesn't make a difference. The key idea is that it is perfectly feasible to do the first step of the Euclidean algorithm for computing gcds. All you need is the remainder upon division of the larger by the smaller of the two numbers. After the first step is done, all of the numbers are in the feasible range.

Comment: thanks by the way i solved it by taking modulo at every step from a-b and using int128 and thanks for your help!